# Performance issue using a bluetooth loudspeaker on Android NDK app

Tags: c++, android-ndk, android-bluetooth

In my Android app, I use Android NDK to play music by doing the following:

- extract audio samples from an OGG file using the [Vorbis library](https://www.xiph.org/vorbis/)
- process the audio samples
- redirect the processed samples to the audio output using the [Oboe library](https://github.com/google/oboe)

In order to avoid underruns, I do the first 2 steps in a separate thread, to extract and process the sound a little bit in advance (it adds a bit of latency, but this is not a problem for my app). That solution works great on every device I've tested so far.

But for some reason, when I pair my device with a bluetooth speaker and when I play music, I have what seems to be underruns on some devices like Samsung S7 or Nokia 1 (but not on every device).

This bug looks so random to me that I don't know where to start. It acts like the bluetooth connection is using quite a lot of CPU so my app doesn't have enough resource to run properly.

Does anyone have experienced something similar? Should I do anything in my code to handle the bluetooth connection so it doesn't use CPU (for example to avoid audio resampling)?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Android + Bluetooth audio is a world of pain. The major thing to appreciate about Bluetooth is the audio sink runs at a rate independent of other audio devices, which is why the native mediaplayer will do things like display video in accordance with whatever rate the attached audio device consumes samples, essentially slaving itself to the clock of the BT audio device. If you want to drive the speed from Android (i.e. SystemClock timebase) you'll need to use a timestretching AudioTrack. (This can be done, but driver support is erratic and overall system stability tanks).

Firstly, you want to eliminate the devices themselves being problems. Can you play the ogg files in a media player to a Bluetooth speaker from the S7 or Nokia 1 without problems? If so, it's your code!

It sounds to me like the speaker is consuming samples faster than the device is producing them, for whatever reason. Basically check your callbacks to make sure whenever the audio subsystem requests more data you are actually providing it. Be sure to drive your decoding pipeline according to the callbacks being made and *not* the system clock or any other assumptions about timing.

Finally, Bluetooth audio, at least A2DP, as opposed to directly streaming MP3, is going to require some processing to recompress the audio as it is sent out, but those devices should have plenty of headroom for this, maybe even special DSPs. I've done it with 1080P video playback at the same time before, and it starts to fall apart with two videos at once!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to play the ogg files with a regular player on the Nokia 1 using a BT speaker, and it works. So, I guess there is something to do in my code, but what? Because without BT device, my player works perfectly fine (no underrun), and surprisingly, it works also perfectly with a BT device on a Asus Zenfone 2...

Comment: Also, when the device is connected to a BT speaker, it's not getting any worse when the app extracts and processes 2 songs at the same time. Which doesn't make any sense to me...